# Array allocated by "malloc" becomes NULL after a "scanf"

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic, malloc, scanf

This code is an exercise on malloc function and dynamic arrays manipulation, it's very simple: the program has to allocate 255 bytes of memory for 255 unsigned characters (the difference with normal integers is that chars occupy only one byte, so I save memory when I don't need a number bigger than 255, it's just a detail), then it asks to the user what he wants to do with that array untill he writes 0, for now the options are just 3. A very simple exercise that allows me to learn to work with dynamic array, but there is a rpoblem that I cannot understand! When I allocate memory everything goes well untill the execution of scan function: after the scanning of the variable "select" the pointer of the array turns into NULL and I cannot figure out why. It cannot be a memory collision issue because the array wouldn't be stored. What can I do?

Here the code and thanks in advance for help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TRY
void main(){
    
    
    //the array is dinamically allocated in the heap memory and when it has a valid address the program starts
    unsigned char select = 1; //this variable is useful for the choice of the utent
    unsigned char length = 0; //this has no need to be explained
    unsigned char index = 0; //this variable can be used as temporary variable in the program
    unsigned char * array = (unsigned char*)malloc(255);
    if(array){
        
        while(select){
            #ifdef TRY
            printf("\t- - Array stored in %p memory address - -\n", array);
            #endif
            
            printf("What wanna do?\n1 - show array\n2 - insert value\n3 - edit value\n0 - quit\n");
            scanf("%d", &select);
            
            //generally the problems start from here: after the scanf the pointer turns into a NULL, you can see by the execution of the next line
            #ifdef TRY
            printf("\t- - Array stored in %p memory address - -\n", array);
            #endif
            switch(select){
                case 0: printf("Bye!\n");
                break;
                
                
                case 1: 
                    printf("Elements: %u\n", length);
                    for(index = 0; index < length; index++) printf("%d\t", *(array+index));
                break;
                
                
                case 2:
                    if(length<255){
                        
                        printf("Write the value to insert in the %p memory address: ", array+length);
                        scanf("%d", (array+length));
                        printf("Value %d added in %p address\n", *(array+length), array+length);
                        
                        length = length+1;
                    }
                    else 
                        printf("Array is full\n");
                break;
                
                
                case 3:
                    printf("Write the index value: ");
                    scanf("%d", &index);
                    if(index<length){
                        
                        printf("Write the value to insert in the %p memory address: ", array+index);
                        scanf("%d", array+index);
                        printf("Value %d written in %p address\n", *(array+length), array+length);
                        
                    }
                    else
                        printf("Invalid index\n");
                break;
                
                
                default: printf("Invalid input\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        free(array);
    }
    else printf("Memory error\n");
}
```

I also tried by allocating the other variables in the same array by the same malloc function, explaining better, I created three unsigned char pointers instead of the first three unsigned char variables and I assigned them the addresses of the last three bytes of the array. The pointer was NULL anymore buuuuuut the array was always empty: after having inserted a value in it, every time the program used the scan function on "select" the array always used to empty. The problem is always the same.

Comment: Compile with warnings: `warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘unsigned char *’` for all your `scanf`s

Comment: `unsigned char select` is the wrong type for `%d`. Follow the compiler warnings.

Comment: @DavidRanieri I tried with your solution but it doesn't work. If you're asking, I'm using the latest version of mingw compiler. Also, curiously I tried the same solution in Visual Studio and it works, what does it even mean?

Comment: @Vice_Quiet_013 compiling with warnings doesn't fix the code, it just gives you a list of things that must be fixed, have you read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74971252/1606345)?

Answer (score 2):

Compile with warnings:

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘unsigned char *’
```

> after the scanning of the variable "select" the pointer of the array
> turns into NULL and I cannot figure out why

Probably `scanf` is writing 4 bytes where you expect to receive a single byte, overwriting contiguous memory areas.

To scan an `unsigned char` switch to:

```
scanf("%hhu", &select);
```

same for `array` and `index`